# Google Classroom Thumbnail

Tags: google-classroom

I'm attempting to [Add a Classroom Share Button](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton) to resources that require authentication. When the "Share to Classroom" button is clicked on a resource, and the assignment (for example) is created in Classroom, the thumbnail, title, and URL are displayed at the bottom of the assignment.

Since the resource is behind authentication, the login screen displays for the thumbnail, and "Login" appears as the title of the link. It appears as though the service that captures the thumbnail and title doesn’t have access to the user’s session in the browser.

This will probably be confusing for teachers and students when they see this login message.

Is there a way to:

A.) suppress the thumbnail/title/URL from displaying?

B.) programmatically affect what is being captured?

C.) anticipate where the request is being made from and present the thumbnail service with a more relevant image/title?

Thanks.

Comment: May I know what is your inquiry regarding Login? Before an app or service can access Classroom data, the app must request authorization from the Classroom user. The app ask for the specific permissions it needs such as username and email address. To authorize permission, the Classroom API uses a very common Internet standard called OAuth https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth .

Comment: Thanks d.datul1990. OAuth is set up, but because the shared resource is behind authentication, and the job that runs on Google's end to grab the screencap doesn't have access to the user's current session, it's only grabbing the resource's login page, rather than its true title and image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to provide custom thumbnails (or title) to avoid the problem that some pages require a login.

You might like to star the [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4398) for this to indicate your interest and receive updates if/when this gets added.